# React: Action vs modifying state variable

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

When is modifying a state variable in a react class component acceptable, and when is it proper to call on an action to change a state variable?

What is the best practice? Would changing a state variable in a react class component go against Flux convention?

Comment: See the React docs on props vs state: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct answer to this question, because it is contextual and depends a lot on your code in general. However, from personal experience I would urge you to refrain from utilizing state variables. It may be acceptable in components without children, but it is still easy to end up having a lot of logic in your component that does not concern itself strictly with presentation (read: rendering).

My opinion: keep your state and data in stores, let the components be incredibly stupid and only deal with rendering and executing actions. This approach makes the app easier to test and ensures readability.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using component state in cases where the data in question is localized and tightly coupled to the component, meaning that it is *only relevant to the component itself* and *unlikely to be needed by any other parts of the application* in the future. Of course you can't anticipate everything, so when in doubt it's probably better to consider it 'application state' and put it in a Store.

Form inputs are one case where this might apply. For example, the transient state of the input fields of a typical user registration or login form is unlikely to ever become relevant to other parts of the application. The data is only used in rendering the component itself and in making the API call that submits the data, so it's natural to think of the state of the form as *part of the form* and use the component state to store it.

A counterexample would be an input for a dynamic search that filters a list in a separate component, where the list should start responding as soon as the user begins typing. Here the transient state of the input should be considered application state and kept in a Store where other components can access it.

Answer (score 0):

You should only ever use actions to write to a store, so if you have state that is a direct representation of what is in a store, then you should only use an action to update it.  There are a lot of options out there but https://github.com/HubSpot/general-store comes with a mixin that lets u bind store data directly to state.

so in your component you could do something like:

```
mixins: [
    GeneralStore.StoreDependencyMixin({
      user: UserStore.get()
    })
]
```

and that would bind whatever data lives in that store into state, when the store is updated so will your components state.  There are also many cases where components have some bit of local state like:

```
getInitialState: ->
  modalOpen: false

openModal: ->
  @setState
    modalOpen: true
```

I have run into some situations where I want to take the data in a store out of sync so that I could keep track of changes and possibly do a reset and list the changes to the model before a user saves and the way i did that is by jsut duplicating the store model in state and mutating that directly, then on save use an action to hit a save endpoint, then pass the newly saved model into the store which would update both the local(out of sync) copy and the main source of truth from the store itself.

Comment: In your second scenario, I wonder if a component shouldn't just have its store or its tightly bound state stored in the single store, for example var store = { .... , myControlBar : { modalOpen: false}, ... }.   At best this keeps things simple and someone later on will know where to find all state.